# Should I pay credit card statement balance despite a refund?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, refund

Statement balance is $1000

Something I bought was refunded so actual balance now is $200

Am I supposed to pay $1000 or $200?

If I pay $1000, my balance will be -$800 but I don't want this to happen since I'm barely using this credit card

Comment: Log into the bank’s web site and aee what the minimum payment is.  If it’s less than $200 then you’re worrying about nothing.

Answer (score 4):

The refund is a *credit*, but not a *payment*.

Your balance is $200. But depending on the timing of the refund, you may have a minimum payment due based on the original $1000 balance. If you have such a minimum payment due, you'll have to pay that (even in the unlikely case that it exceeds $200, because the refund is on the *next* billing cycle). But on the next billing cycle, your minimum payment would reflect your decreased balance due to the refund.

(I was in a similar situation years ago, where I had a refund post following my closing date that exceeded my minimum payment due. I though the refund would count as a payment, so I did nothing. Next statement, I had a late charge. I was able to convince them to remove the late charge, but lesson learned.)

Answer (score 4):

If the refund is registered on your account, you should be in a position to consult the CC company and request that a reduced payment be accepted (perhaps the full balance then remaining)

In general, the CC company will accept that position without question but don't take it for granted. You **MUST** seek advance approval or you may well be hit with interest charges if the full amount (as shown on the statement) is not paid.